# c++ multithreading function calls with parameters by reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, reference

I am using a library which uses multithreading to call member functions when an event happens. Each "handler" in the library has a thread which can call function `MyClass::Process(const Signal& signal)`. MyClass has a reference to a `Catalog` class called `cat`.

Inside of `Process` I have the following code:

```
Stats stats;//simple container struct to hold values

std:string id(signal.signalId());
//set values of stats here based on the values in signal

cat->onSignalUpdate(id, stats);
```

From the libary's documentation:

> It's impossible in bounds of single instance of Handler to have two
>   user callbacks to be invoked simultaneously. However, different
>   instances of Handler for different channels are not linked with each
>   other, therefore invocations from different Handler instances may
>   occur in parallel.

Catalog has a member `std::map<std::string, Stats> signal_map`

Inside of `Catalog::onSignalUpdate(const std::string& id, const Stats& stats)`

```
std::map<std::string, Stats>::iterator it(signal_map.find(id));
if(it != signal_map.end())
{
    it->second = stats;
}
```

This works much of the time, where the proper Ids are mapped to the appropriate Stats struct. Occasionally I am getting improper matching where an ID of Handler A, is being assigned to a struct belonging to that of Handler B. It appears to me that the function is being called in parallel. I was under the impression that in threading, calls to functions, while done in parallel, are duplicated. Is this not the case, or is there an issue with passing values by reference in threads?

Comment: Stats is struct or class? Why do you think that two handlers cannot have sameid? I mean maybe you got correct result?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're not protecting `signal_map` form concurrent access.

Comment: @IlyaBursov Stats is a struct. I am certain that the two handlers cannot have the same id

Comment: @WhozCraig If the handlers cannot have the same id, why do I need to protect the map? I am not protecting it, but I guess I am not following why I would need to if the Ids are never the same.

Comment: Do all handlers use the same map? Is said-map modified *ever* (inserting or removing elements) by different threads *concurrently*? If either is true, it *has* to be latched for *any* access, not just writes, and certainly not how you currently have it, which is *not at all*. See Mats answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have updated the question to reflect the questions posed by Matt. The map is never modified in terms of inserting or removing elements. Will that still affect the concurrency issue?  It seems like parallel calls to the function are overwriting each other's local variables

Comment: It should not affect it at all. If the map is indeed static there is something else we're not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update a `std::map` from multiple threads without some form of protection against multiple threads modifying the `map` at the same time. You need a mutex or something along those lines. In partciular, if `id` is "new", then a the underlying data structures (typically a "RB-tree") in the map will be altered. This MUST not be done from multiple threads. You also can't access the tree to "read" while it is being modified, as the entries in the tree may be "half-updated" (e.g. the next element is pointing to an element that hasn't been properly filled in or some such).

Comment: The map is prefilled and also I check to make sure the id is in there, let me edit my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Joshua thats important, so you should definitely add it to the question.

Comment: I've updated the question. This guarantees that the map contains the id itself. It seems like parallel calls to the function are overwriting each other's local variables.